# Перенаправление на модальное окно

Tags: html, phpmailer

Есть html код:`

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
      <div class="popup-title">Форма обратной связи</div>
      <!-- /.popup-title -->
      <div class="popup-close">&times;</div>
      <!-- /.popup-close -->
      <div class="popup-form">
        <form action="mailer/smart.php" method="POST" class="main-form form_post">
          <div class="popup-form-header">Получите индивидуальное предложение <br>
            <span>на производство и поставку</span>
            <label for="phone" class="popup-form__label">
              Введите ваш номер телефона:
            </label>
            <input type="tel" class="popup-form__input" id="phone" name="user" placeholder="+7 (ХХХ) ХХХ-ХХ-ХХ" required><!--Если пункт списка не выбран, браузер выведет сообщение, а форма отправлена не будет-->
            <button class="button popup-form__btn">
              Оставить заявку!
            </button>
            <div class="popup-form__note">
                *Минимальный заказ 500шт
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.popup-form-header -->
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- /.popup-form -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.popup -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.overlay -->
```

[image]

> Мне нужно, чтобы после заполнения формы и отправки появлялось такое же
>   модальное окно, только с блогодарностью. Вот html код с
>   благодарностью:

```
    <div class="over_wrap" >
    <div class="popup_thanks">
      <div class="popup-title">заявка оформлена!</div>
      <!-- /.popup-title -->
      <div class="popup-close_thanks">&times;</div>
      <!-- /.popup-close -->
      <div class="popup-form_thanks">
          <div class="popup-form-header">
            Благодарим вас за интерес к нашей компании!
            <span>Вы оставили заявку, с вами свяжется наш специалист в ближайшее время!</span>
          </div><!-- /.popup-form-header -->

      </div>
      <!-- /.popup-form -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.popup -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.overlay -->
```

> Часть кода php:

```
    if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Письмо не может быть отправлено. ';
    echo 'Ошибка: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    header('location: ../index.html');
}
```

> Форма Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mailer/smart.php",
    // url: "mail.php",
    data: self.serialize()
 }).done(function() {
    $('.over_wrap').show();
    $('.over_wrap').fadeIn('slow');
 setTimeout(function() {
     $(".overlay").fadeOut();
    }, 1500);
    setTimeout(function() {
     $(".over_wrap").fadeOut();
    }, 2000);
    // setTimeout('',2000);
    $(".form_post").trigger("reset");
 });
    return false;
```

Comment: Что нужно добавить в php?

Comment: если вы отправляете к примеру форму ajax то там есть такой метод

Comment: @МаксимЛенский  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "mailer/smart.php",
  // url: "mail.php",
  data: self.serialize()
  }).done(function() {
  $('.over_wrap').show();
  $('.over_wrap').fadeIn('slow');
  setTimeout(function() {
   $(".overlay").fadeOut();
  }, 1500);
  setTimeout(function() {
   $(".over_wrap").fadeOut();
  }, 2000);
  // setTimeout('',2000);
  $(".form_post").trigger("reset");
  });
    return false;
А что мне тогда в php прописать?

Answer (score 0):

А в php нужно было добавить: `header('location: ../index.html');` А ведь было у меня так изначально